# Como criar Regras de acesso a um plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Estou desenvolvendo um plugin para REDMINE. Tenho um `menu` criado utilizando o `:top_menu`, sendo assim ele fica na parte superior do REDMINE , junto à Administração , etc...

Porém , eu quero que nem todos os usuários logados no sistema , veja este "Botão". Somente Usuários que eu designar que seja feita a visualização.

Isso é possível, e quais regras de acesso devo criar?

Answer (score 1):

é só verificar se o nivel do usuário logado é aquele...

```
<%= user_current? %> Botão <% end %>
```